# Подскажите аналог f-строк в С++

Tags: c++

Мне нужно, чтобы переменные, которые находятся в фигурных скобках, принимали заданные значения.
Код такого вида:

```
QString compression_level = "8";
QString sample_fmt = "s16";
QString sampling_rate = "48000";
QString preset = "-compression_level {compression_level} -sample_fmt {sample_fmt} -sample_rate={sampling_rate}";
```

В Python для этого используются так называемые f-строки:

> `f"-compression_level {compression_level} -sample_fmt {sample_fmt} -sample_rate={sampling_rate}"`.

Имеется ли в С++ что-то подобное?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qstring.html#arg

Answer (score 1):

В C++20 добавили библиотеку [fmt](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) в [стандартную библиотеку](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format). Пока что она отсутствует в популярных реализациях, поэтому вот [пример](https://godbolt.org/z/4dveGT), в котором в будущем надо заменить `#include <fmt/core.h>` на `#include <format>`, а `fmt::` – на `std::`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fmt/core.h>

int main() {
    std::cout << fmt::format("{}, {}\n", "hello", "world");
}
```

Пока можно довольствоваться [`std::printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf):

```
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    std::printf("%d\n%zu\n", 42, sizeof(42));
}
```